# TypeScript not enforcing return type using Pick

Tags: typescript

Is this an intended behavior of Pick? Because I suppose TypeScript would prompt an error when a different object type is returned.

The expected return type is `{ title: string }` but a type of `{ title: string; completed: boolean }` is returned instead.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQNUgADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRogLFFTBPB3AExcwABT0xnM9zsyhc9wASmCKhwDQ8ZC8iElzhB7Bo3zcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiS58D0Ii8AoZTJZggFSRxAvADlQAHJhAA5SASAVBFQAeW+ZF2gldWkgx1QjgUrmkeFATgtOlGWH0KAQiBhwiudokkuiIgMHBx3RYbC43CCigyCjIyR6uHg3AwAG9FCVUPJ3PlrqhKJxmLP4fpyfP4JwlzTV+uSnWWUWlyCFR5OIoAL7BVAtbwT+C0JyVxN8uiegA8xsn-AFedUHcUMAB9BRPdwiwFAA+SldxpepJyXP8XzfCgP35Gc5wXSAlwFABhRovDYJABV4DdILzSBuCXUdoGzCi7xKWUEJoRA8HQSdPxVPUl1oH9UP4aMgPcaMYL5CTsJKMs80JTJn1AFQ4xWMg2DIW8gA)

```
interface Todo {
  title: string
  description: string
  completed: boolean
}

// Pick "title" and "completed" from Todo
type TodoPreview = Pick<Todo, "title" | "completed">

// Creating a TodoPreview object
const todo: TodoPreview = {
  title: "Clean room",
  completed: false,
}
  
const mytodo = (): Pick<Todo, "title"> => {
    return todo // No error returning a TodoPreview
}
```

Comment: This works as expected. You can return an object with more properties if it covers what the interface has. If the interface says you have `a` and you pass `a` and `b` to it, that's not an issue, since the compiler will ensure you won't call `obj.b`. See [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

Comment: I'd say the point here is important enough to be formed as a standalone answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is basically the same as this:

```
interface Animal {
   color?: string;
}

interface Bird extends Animal {
   canFly: boolean
}

function getAnimalColor(animal: Animal): Animal | undefined {
   return animal.color ? animal : undefined;
}

const duck: Bird = {
   color: 'brown',
   canFly: true
}

const animalColor = getAnimalColor(duck);

console.log(animalColor)
```

Since `duck` is an instance of `Bird` which is also an instance of `Animal`, this is acceptable. Using `Pick` in this manner is another way to achieve polymorphism.

Maybe [this proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) is what you're looking for. It looks like a lot of people want the same thing.